# action bar menu icon is not showing properly after gradle update

Tags: java, android, xml

Before update gradle it was awesome but after update its changed to

[image: invoice_history]

Actually I was using appcompat v7:26.0.0 and it was working fine but after downgrade to 25.0.0( due to a customization) ,  I found that problem and I tried to fix it but I was disappointed and I also  configured back to 26.0.0 but I am getting this problem till now. How to fix it ?

There is no icon size issue because till yesterday it was ok.

**my code which i am using is**

**Manifeast.xml**

```
  <activity
       android:name=".ui_activities.MyInvoicesList"
       android:label="@string/label"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**menu_download.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:icon="@drawable/ic_cloud_download_black_24dp"
          android:title="Download Invoices"
          android:id="@+id/menu_downloadInvoices"
          app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
</menu>
```

**My Java Code is**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_download, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Post the icon drawable XML. And where you set the icon.

Comment: Screen shot of app is given in link please open it.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzunGCq9Z3kec3ljMTVtUXg4V0k/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I know how the result looks. I want to find out why it looks like this. That's why I need to see the code.

Comment: Sure, but i'll post my code in morning because right now I dont have my computer

Comment: I used oncreateoptionmenu and menu xml file with AppTheme

Comment: The icon is PNG or vector XML? Try both options.

Comment: I have tried both with different size but problem is same.

Comment: i have maintained my code above

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using correct size of icons 24*24

Actually I was using icon with 96*96 thats why I was getting that bug I have updated my icon size and fixed it